# How to switch of the drum sound (at login) for ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: sound, login

I installed ubuntu tweaks but this seems not to have a possibility to switch off the drum sound. What else can I try?

Comment: I am sorry, but I overlooked a very simple way: The sound can simply be switched off at the start-up page (where you are asked for login).  That solves the problem immediately.

Answer (score 1):

**Ubuntu Tweaks should have that possibility**

You need to open the Tweak Tab and select the "Login Settings" option. There you can see the Play Login Sound option select with the possibility for on/off. Note: You need to click on the unlock button first to be able to change the Play Login Sound option.

A non-Tweaks option is:

```
gksudo gedit /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/50_unity-greeter.gschema.override
```

Insert following lines:

```
[com.canonical.unity-greeter]
play-ready-sound = false
```

Save and run following command:

```
sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
```

[Courtesy of liberiangeek.net](https://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/05/disable-the-ready-drum-sound-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/)

Comment: There is no "login settings" in Unity tweak tool